# Where is amazon aws auto scale image

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created an autoscale group in AWS. I am wondering it may have an image being created. Can I know where is the image of the instance being put?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would be using any of your existing Amazon machine image while creating the Autoscaling group and the instances that automatically gets launched during the peak time will be of the same AMI which you have specified in the autoscaling group.

Basically, you should have an AMI of the Instance, which Autoscaling will be using at the demand time.

Once after configuring the Autoscaling command line, using the autoscaling commands you have to tell Autoscaling which AMI should be used to launch an Instance at the time of demand.